# Classical harmony

Tags: harmony

Our harmony professor gave us this for homework and since I skipped a few classes because it seemed super easy, now I can't figure which are the chord functions (all chords are either 1, 4 or 5) and I don't understand what are the sharps notated for, it's something linked to the sharp 7 of the scale.

[image]

Comment: Doing homework for people is frowned upon here.

Comment: I don t want exact answers, just explanation of what i missed in the class. There will still be the need to exercise after that

Comment: @ tim, what is the difference  between answering the question of a student who has missed something in theory and the one of an absolute beginner who plays or writes something quite elementary and asks for help?
as your answers are meant to help each other ... the solution  to a problem of a student will benefit later to problems of the beginner of today.

Comment: @ Catalin Petre: may I ask as "your teacher", as you have to finish this homework why not post here at least your own notation instead the photo of the blackboard of your classroom, it would be much easier for someone to read it.
and may be by writing your problem you might already found the solution. thank you. I will have to complete my profile "my philosophy of teaching":
learning by doing, learning by trial and error, learning by problem solving and developing yourself, learning reading by writing, learning by trying to explain something to someone else, learning by asking a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to know what you missed, but it seems that it could be to do with minor keys and the 'raised leading note'. With this being in G minor- from the key sig.it's either Bb major or G minor - the leading note in minor keys is often raised to be the pitch one semitone under the key's root. Thus harmony wise, it'll produce a proper perfect cadence of D(7) > Gm. That's where the F# comes in as an accidental.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's answer is correct.

The sharps are concerning the f# and the the numbers in front of the sharp are assigning the inversion of the chords (D6, D56, D2 and D 46) that is the dominant of g minor.you have to study this stuff.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(music)#Chords